# Rails: Mailer won't send mail from a rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, actionmailer

I've written a plugin that extends Redmine `Mailer` model, which in turn extends `ActionMailer`, and adds some custom messages to it.
When I call these newly added `Mailer` methods from an `after_save` callback of a different model (like `Mailer.estimation_exceeded(msg_options).deliver`), I reveive the expected email.

I have also written a `rake` task that triggers the same Mailer methods. The problem here is that though the method gets triggered and I see message info in the log, I don't receive actual emails. Any idea what might be the problem?

**UPD:**
Current mailer configuration is the following:

```
# default configuration options for all environments
default:
  # Outgoing emails configuration (see examples above)
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :async_smtp
    async_smtp_settings:
      address: mail.domain
      port: 25
      domain: mail.domain
      authentication: :login
      user_name: user@mail.domain"
      password: "***"
      raise_delivery_errors: true
      perform_deliveries: true
```

Comment: Which environment is this for? Have you ensured that the `raise_delivery_errors` and `perform_deliveries` flags have been enabled in your environment configuration?

Comment: @nicohvi, I've updated the queston with current mailer config. Nothing changed after I explicitly defined these params.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification. Can you see what the environment is during the rake task execution?

Comment: @nicohvi, I've added `puts "#{ENV['RAILS_ENV']}, #{ENV['RACK_ENV']}"` in my rake task. RAILS_ENV shows development, and RACK_ENV is empty. Setting it to development as well doesn't help.